# How to Fix: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "" in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, geom

I have seen many questions about this error already. But seems nothing worked for me.
Please share your suggestions.
Here is my query, where I am trying to update the new_shp_id column of geonames tables, from geoboundaries table when geom of both tables intersect.

```
UPDATE 
    public.geonames
SET 
    new_shp_id = subquery.gbID
FROM 
    (
        SELECT gb.shapeid AS gbID
            FROM "public"."geoBoundaries" gb, "public"."geonames" gn
    ) AS subquery
WHERE 
    ST_Intersects(gn.geom, gb.geom);
```

Error:

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "gn"
>  LINE 11:
> ST_Intersects(gn.geom, gb.geom);

Comment: In the call to `ST_Intersects`, only the `subquery` table is known, because that's the only table in the corresponding `FROM` clause. Well, plus the `public.geonames` table, which is the target of the `UPDATE`. You can expose the `geom` columns (in that table) by adding them to the `SELECT` list within `subquery`. You'll need to provide unique derived column names.

Comment: Also note the cross join behavior in your approach.  Just use @a_horse_with_no_name ' s approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the derived table. Just put the geoboundaries directly in the FROM clause and give an alias to the target table:

```
UPDATE public.geonames gn
  SET new_shp_id = gb.shapeid
FROM "public"."geoBoundaries" gb
WHERE ST_Intersects(gn.geom, gb.geom);
```

Comment: Thanks it was helpful. Just little change to get it done, since subquery alias does not exist any more. `UPDATE public.geonames gn
  SET new_shp_id = gb.shapeid 
FROM "public"."geoBoundaries" gb
WHERE ST_Intersects(gn.geom, gb.geom);`